# Force a stored procedure to run single threaded

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, single-threaded

I have a stored procedure running on a multi-core system. It is executed in multi-threaded way. Due to, may be, some thing in the query, execution of some of the threads hangs forever with cx_packet wait and lock. Is there a way to force single threaded execution? (I know that is not the best solution, but is helpful until at least the query is better optimized.)

Answer (score 6):

You can add `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)` to the statements that you want to run single threaded. Example

```
SELECT *
FROM master..spt_values
OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

Comment: Thanks Martin but that would just be for each single query. It won't make the entire Transaction in the SP single threaded.

Comment: @FaithWins - Yes that's correct. This is defined at query level there is no way of setting it for every statement in a module so you would need to do it for all statements in the stored procedure that cause the problem. The only other thing you could do (dependant on edition of SQL Server) would be to look at using [resource governor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933866.aspx) and run the procedure from a workload group with `MAXDOP=1`

Comment: That is interesting except for two gotchas. 1. I have SQL Server 2005 and 2. It looks like a server level setting which will affect all other transactions to the server. 
I will give the MAXDOP a try. Thanks again for the help.